# Angular2+Jasmine, unit test, import testing modular-404 not found

Tags: jasmine, angular

import {describe,expect,it,xit, inject, beforeEachProviders} from "angular2/testing";

without this line of code, I can run my Jasmine simple test code successfully. But for more complicated code, I need to import modular from "angular2/testing"

Error: Failed to load resource 404. As it looks for the file in this path: project_folder/angular2/testing instead of project_folder/node_modules/angular2/testing.

Here is my test.html file:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });
    System.import('app/test.spec')
            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "live": "live-server",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "1.3.1",
    "live-server": "^0.9.0"
  }
}
```

Finally, I solved the problem by adding the following scripts: (note: system.src.js should be added before testing.dev.js)

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `test.dev.js` file using a `<script>` element in your HTML file:

```
<head>
  (...)
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/test.dev.js"></script>
  (...)
</head>
```

The `angular2/testing` module is registered into this file...

Comment: Hi@Thierry Tempiler. After adding the above code, there still some errors. But I solved this problem by adding the other scripts, see my posts. Although I don't know why we need those scripts.